# Browser Compatibility issue list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best guides to HTML5 & CSS3 support in web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831243/what-are-the-best-guides-to-html5-css3-support-in-web-browsers)

I am always having problems with browser compatability and I think everyone has experienced this on web pages sometimes. It is really annoying and I am wondering if there is something like a list that lists browser compatibility issues?

I found several "Top 10 of CSS (JS) compatibility issues" lists or blog posts, but I am really seeking for something more extensive.

Comment: Quirksmode.org is a good start: http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

Comment: Is there something that targets JS compatability issues?

Comment: Quirksmode does have some JS compatibility charts too: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html not to mention the very outdated Visibone charts show all the functions, with symbols to portray compatibility http://www.visibone.com/javascript/charts.html

Comment: I don't see a point on closing this! This question is absolutely unrelated to HTML5. Most cross browser problems occurr due to the use of IE6 etc. Closing this question has no justification.

Answer (score 3):

For CSS Compatibility list, head over to;

[When Can I Use..](http://caniuse.com/)